# Dynamically change pen color & paint when clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, graphics

## The Program

I'm playing around and learning about graphics using visual basic (coming from C++). I've made a program and I want to do two things: paint when the left mouse button is pressed, and stop when released, and **also** I want to be able to change the pen color using a colordialog. After hours of frustration, I've yet to combat these two problems.

## The Code (Snippet)

```
Private obj As Graphics
Dim rect As Rectangle

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    obj = RichTextBox1.CreateGraphics
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    obj.Dispose()
End Sub

 Private Sub RichTextBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.MouseMove

    With rect
        .X = e.X
        .Y = e.Y
        .Width = TrackBar1.Value
        .Height = TrackBar1.Value
    End With

    If ToolStripButton1.Checked = True Then
        obj.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rect)
    ElseIf ToolStripButton2.Checked = True Then
        obj.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)
    End If

    ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = (e.X & ", " & e.Y)

End Sub
```

### Past Attempts (and frustrations)

My idea originally was to do this:

```
Dim myPen = New Pen(ButtonWithDC1.BackColor)
```

But doing so gave me an error message. I looked at Microsoft's documentation, but it wasn't useful for what I'm trying to do. I can create a pen just fine, but I'd like for the user to be able to change the color while the app is currently running.

### GUI Layout

[image]

I don't have an attempt at my other problem (drawing while pressing the mouse down, not just by moving the mouse -- like a normal paint program), I don't even have a starting point for that solution. Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Hoping someone can answer this as well. I'm trying to make a petty replica of MSPaint.

Comment: paint/draw in the paint event (using the Graphics provided) otherwise your drawing will disappear when windows updates the display (such as something moves across it).  beyond that, use the MouseDown and MouseUp events to track the start and stop of drawing

Comment: Yes, I plan on implementing that bit at the end, I'm just experimenting at the moment on solving these two problems @Plutonix

Comment: What was the error message that you got?

Comment: Assuming you have the color from the dialog then use `System.Drawing.Pen(theColor)` to create a pen of the desired color. MouseUp/Dn **is** the solution to controlling when mousemove actually draws a line

Comment: @the_lotus "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I understand that a color isn't a brush, I'm pretty sure that's what it's implying I believe. But if that's the case, I dont see how else I'm going to do this.

Comment: Create the Pen each time you draw to the control (using the paint event as suggested).  You can store the current chosen colour in a module level variable if you want.

Comment: @Plutonix, The argument that "System.Drawing.Pen()" takes is something like Pen.color, not just a color. I believe that's what was troubling me

Comment: I added a picture to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. The buttons you click determine the pen color when the app is running.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit more involved than you think, and SO is not keen on multiple questions per post (not in your nest interest either -  someone might know A and not B so wont bother answering).

To draw on Mousemove when the mouse is down, you need to track when the mouse is down (question A):

```
Private _mouseDown As Boolean
Private _mouseLoc As Point 
Private _mouseNewLoc As Point

sub Ctl_MouseDown(sender...
  ' ToDo: add logic to check which button....
   _mouseDown = True 
   _mouseLoc = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
End Sub

sub Ctl_MouseUp(sender...
   _mouseDown = False
End Sub
```

Then mousemove can be used to capture the current location

```
Sub Ctl_MouseMove(sender....
     If _mouseDn Then
          _mouseNewLoc = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
          Ctl.invalidate    ' call to paint
     End If
End Sub

' selected color from dialog or whereever
Private myColor As Color
Sub Ctl_Paint(sender....

    If _mouseDn Then
        ' Pen ctor is overloaded...(Question B)
        Using p As New Pen(myColor)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, _mouseLoc, _mouseNewLoc)
           ' plus more....
        End Using
    End If
```

This only addresses the questions posed; the bigger issue you have is tracking what has already been drawn.  This will draw a line only while the mouse is down, but for a polygon or shape, you have to add code to redraw those parts.  Either a List of the points which make up a polygon, or maybe save what you have to a bitmap and add to it.  Thats a bit outside the scope of the question and depends on app factors.  You also need a Drawing start/stop or way to signal when to stop adding lines or ovals or whatever (ovals are sort of simple: one at a time, lines as part of a shape will take some work).

Either way all painting has to take place in the Paint event (or OnPaint) if you want to see the shape/drawing/image develop.

Answer (score 2):

Place a button (Button1) and picturebox (PictureBox1) on a form, also add a colordialog (ColorDialog1).

This code will allow you to draw on the picture box and choose the color using a color you select from the colordialog. The MouseDown event writes a flag that the mouse is down, and stores the last location. The MouseUp does similar. The MouseMove actually draws. Use a line and the last location.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private myColor As Color = Color.Black
    Private mouseIsDown As Boolean = False
    Private previousLocation As System.Nullable(Of System.Drawing.Point) = Nothing

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        myColor = If(ColorDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK, ColorDialog1.Color, myColor)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
        mouseIsDown = True
        previousLocation = e.Location
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        If mouseIsDown Then
            If previousLocation IsNot Nothing Then
                Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
                    g.DrawLine(New Pen(myColor), previousLocation.Value, e.Location)
                End Using
                PictureBox1.Invalidate()
            End If
            previousLocation = e.Location
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
        mouseIsDown = False
        previousLocation = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
    End Sub
End Class
```